Conflict between TikZ math library and Beamer Metropolis + XeLaTeX
I am having trouble using the TikZ library math in a Beamer  metropolis document compiled with XeLaTeX. I need XeLaTeX to use the beautiful Fira fonts.
Here is an example:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
    
\tikzmath{\x1 = 1; \y1 = 2 ;    \x2 = \x1+1; \y2 = \y1+1 ;} 
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test TikZ math}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thick, ] (\x1, \y1)--(\x2, \y2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}  

This code works fine with pdfLaTeX but not with XeLaTeX. Is there a workaround?
Thanks for your help!


I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer. This can cause a whole number of problems, like missing text in note pages, incorrect overlays etc. You can use lualatex if you need special fonts.
I also would replace the metropolis theme with moloch, which is an updated fork with a lot of bug fixes.

With moloch, your example compiles without errors:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont[
  BoldFont={Fira Sans}, BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic},
  ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic},
]{Fira Sans Light}
\setmathfont{Fira Math Light}

\begin{document}
    
\tikzmath{\x1 = 1; \y1 = 2 ;    \x2 = \x1+1; \y2 = \y1+1 ;} 
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test TikZ math}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thick, ] (\x1, \y1)--(\x2, \y2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}  



awesome, thanks!!

@Andros You're welcome!
